# Transform Javascript XPath in valid PHP query() XPath | normalize JS XPath --> PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xml, dom, xpath

This is valid XPath in Javascript:

```
id("priceInfo")/div[@class="standardProdPricingGroup"]/span[1]
```

And this turned into valid PHP XPath to be used with DOMXPath->query() is

```
//*[@id="priceInfo"]//div[@class="standardProdPricingGroup"]//span[1]
```

1. do you know any libraries or custom components that already do this transformation?
2. do you know available documentation that lists the two syntax differences?

My main concern is that there could be a lot of differences, and I am looking to identify these differences, and I have problems to identify these.

The question could be put also in different way: **Since Javascript can have different valid XPath formats, how to normalize them to work with the PHP.**

One of the updates also mention that the id() function is valid XPath if there is a valid DTD that contains this definition. I don't have power over the input DTD, and if there is a way to find a solution that works without any specific DTD it would be awesome.

**Update:**

I want to transform the first format into the second with an algorithm. My input is the first one and not the second one. Can't change this.

As @Nison Maël pointed out, the 2nd format is valid Javascript XPath as presented here: http://jsbin.com/elatum/2/edit this unfortunately just adds to the problem of Javascript XPath "fragmentation".

@salathe pointed out that the valid Javascript XPath query works fine in PHP if the input documented has valid DTD ( @Dimitre Novatchev mentioned this in a comment, but overlooked the importance). Unfortunately I don't have control of the input DTD, so now I have to investigate a way to overcome this, or to find a solution that works even without valid DTD.

Comment: This is a great question! It doesn't look like there's any documentation out there (at least not through a cursory google search). I'm excited to see the answer to this one.

Comment: The first expression is a legal XPath expression. However, for the Xpath function `id()` to work, the XML must have a DTD and element definitions in the DTD must have attributes thet have the `ID` keyword.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: And what about the translation of `//` to `/`?

Comment: @choroba Java is not mentioned once in this whole question. Also, `id()` is a *node set function* mentioned in the very spec you linked to.

Comment: I do not think that javascript has a much different xpath than php. I mean the xpath language should be the same, right? Can you please add to which javascript xpath you are referring to specifically? For php it's clear, there is only one. but wait, there is more than one but you already wrote you are referring to the standard DOMDocument extension, right.

Comment: And both xpath are actually not identical, please clarify which of the two results is wanted: http://jsbin.com/elatum/4/edit

Comment: @hakre actually, they're pretty much different in several places. The first one constituting the gist of the question (selection of a group of nodes vs. selecting one using `id()`), others seemingly accidental (`/` for `child` axis in the first one and `//` for `descendant-or-self` axis in the second one). Perhaps this should be clarified as well.

Comment: The 2nd one in your example which yields to 1 exact answer and not two is what I want to work even if I have an invalid DTD definition.

Comment: @choroba -- `//someName` *isn't` equivalent to `/someName` -- therefore one shouldn't be translated into the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just seeing that Salathe actually answered the same, but taking your comment into account and to stress this a bit more:

You do not need to specify any DTD. As long as you use the `DOMDocument::loadHTML` or `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` functions, the HTML `id` attribute is actually registered for the the xpath `id()` function. With the demo HTML given in http://jsbin.com/elatum/2/edit, you even get an error when you load the document:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): ID priceInfo already defined in ...

Which is already a sign that this is a true ID attribute because it moans about duplicates. A related sample code looks like:

```
$xpath = 'id("priceInfo")/div[@class="standardProdPricingGroup"]/span[1]';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile(__DIR__ . '/../data/file-11796340.html');
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

$r = $xp->query($xpath);
echo $xpath, "\n";
echo $r ? $r->length : 0, ' elements found', "\n";
if (!$r) return;
foreach($r as $node) {
    echo " - ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
id("priceInfo")/div[@class="standardProdPricingGroup"]/span[1]
1 elements found
 - hello
```

In case you need more control, first run an xpath to mark all HTML `id` attributes as ID for xpath:

```
$r = $xp->query("//*[@id]");
if ($r) foreach($r as $node) {
    $node->setIdAttribute('id', true);
}
```

You can then use the same xpath with the `id()` function, no need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just translate `id("...")` to `//*[@id="..."][1]` at the start of your expression?

For instance, if can assume you won't have any parentheses in the `id(...)` expressions:

```
$queryRewritten =   preg_replace('/^id\(([^\)]+)\)/','//*[@id=$1][1]',$query);
```

[Sample code](http://so.viperpad.com/QWSTqs)

EDIT: corrected the replacement, id() imust be the first in the expression

Comment: It helps, but I am curious what other undocumented stuff can come up in the future.

Comment: It's not really undocumented stuff, the XPATH specs are quite clear about this behaviour. The undocumented part is about the browser DOM engine implicitly applying a Doctype to the HTML DOM.

Comment: @Pentium10 Maybe you need to be more explicit about what you're trying to achieve

Comment: As said in the last line of my updated question that I want to find a solution that is independent of DTD.

Comment: Apart from a document using a different namespace prefix, which could trick the wpath engine. Or a DTD which specifies default implied values for attributes (which should never be the case for HTML). You should be safe

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer but it's too big to put as a comment and it may help you a little.

If you have control over the input XML, then instead of using a DTD to declare `id` attributes, you can declare them explicitly in the XML document itself by prefixing `id` attributes with `xml:`.

For example, if you had XML of

```
<foo id="x27"/>
```

and changed it to

```
<foo xml:id="x27"/>
```

then the id() function would recognise that attribute as a formal XML `id` type, not just as an attribute with the name `id`.

I know this "trick" works on the Saxon processor, but I must admit I've not tried it with PHP.

[W3C xml:id](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/)

Comment: PHP's [`DOMElement::setIdAttribute`](http://de.php.net/DOMElement.setIdAttribute) allows to specify the name of the `xml:id` attribute regardless of the input (and without changing it). An example is in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11819341/367456)